# how to reload repeater on button click in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have a repeater on my page being populated on page load

```
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader postView = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        topicView.DataSource = postView;
        topicView.DataBind();
```

And then I have a section to add a post. What I want it to do is when the user presses add, it reloads the page and displays the updated repeater. However it's not doing this

Everyone has said just reload the databind, except that isn't working as the original databind is in the page load, and the new databind is in a protected void button click.

Can anyone tell me how to do this, or do I just need to place ALL the connection, datasource ad databind info in the button click code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a function that can be call everytime Button click event fire

```
 Private void BindRepeater()
 {
     con.Open();
    SqlDataReader postView = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    topicView.DataSource = postView;
    topicView.DataBind();
  }

  Protected Button_Click(object as sender , EventArgs e)
 {
   //call the function to populate the repeater with the updated records
   this.BindRepeater();

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can resolve it like this . create a method

```
private void Bind()
{
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader postView = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        topicView.DataSource = postView;
        topicView.DataBind();
}
```

now you can use it anywhere on the page where you need to reload the repeater.